# Command+backquote (switch to next window) shortcut no longer works correctly in Mail after upgrading to Ventura

Tags: mail.app, shortcut, ventura

This is a very strange one. I just upgraded to Ventura (13.0.1) and have discovered that for some reason the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, which is supposed to cycle through windows of the currently active app, no longer works properly when the active app is Mail.

Specifically, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> will bring focus to the *next* window, but after cycling through all of the windows once, it will not return to the first window again.  So if I have, say, a draft open in a separate window, plus the Message Viewer in another window, I can't toggle back and forth between them using the shortcut — I can use it once, and it's effectively a one-way trip.  Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> does work for going backward, but frankly, that's a pain, and it never used to work this way.

I have verified that in Finder and Safari, the keyboard shortcut still works the way it used to, so this seems to be specific to Mail.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening, or if there is some way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I still don't know why this was happening, but I now know how to fix it:  just updated to Ventura 13.1, and the problem is solved.